# How to use Java to set different colors in one cell in Excel

Tags: java, excel, colors, cell, jxl

I am currently stuck in using JXL to set different colors in one cell for Excel. I searched a lot but found the JXL may not support this feature. So I am wondering is there any other Lib or way using Java to set different colors in one cell at the same time?

**For example: the string "apple" should display in the cell like "app" in blue and "le" in red.**

Thank you all for the support, very appreciated.

Comment: Check Apache POI. I'm voting to close this question becasue too broad.

Comment: Hi Pirho, thank you for your reply. I'm the beginner of using Java Excel, as far as I can find is all about change color for one cell which is not corresponding to my question. would you mind give me some hints like which method or do I need to override the method of POI? Thank you

Comment: I may find the solution, I will try it first and give the feedback later

Comment: You need to put some code in question -by editing it -  what have you done and what is the problem otherwise people are not able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the POI demo example:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
    Row row = sheet.createRow((short)0);
    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(1);
    XSSFRichTextString rt = new XSSFRichTextString("The quick brown fox");


    XSSFFont font1 = wb.createFont();
      font1.setBold(true);
      font1.setColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0)));
      rt.applyFont(0, 10, font1);

      XSSFFont font2 = wb.createFont();
      font2.setItalic(true);
      font2.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_DOUBLE);
      font2.setColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 0)));
      rt.applyFont(10, 19, font2);

      XSSFFont font3 = wb.createFont();
      font3.setColor(new XSSFColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255)));
      rt.append(" Jumped over the lazy dog", font3);

      cell.setCellValue(rt);


    OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("E:/test111.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
```